# Can I put an http psw on a site and still let Facebook REALTIME apis through?

Tags: http, authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I'm working on a site that is using Facebook authentication and friends, but I'm not ready for it to be publicly visible. It seems like if I put a password on the site's directory, Facebook's calls to my server won't be able to get in.  Is there a way to provide FB with user/psw credentials for the site -- just http basic authentication or something comparable, I guess -- so that it will be able to get in?

EDIT BASED ON CLARIFICATION AND MORE EXPERIMENTATION:

There are looking to be two parts to this:

- There are no problems with Facebook Connect.  When the user visits the page of the protected site, they're presented with the authentication panel, and they then authenticate (or don't).  If they get it, the connection/login follows, and all's well, since the connect information is presumably coming back along the same http connection that's just been authenticated.  (I'm a little fuzzy on these parts of http work, but I think that's mostly correct.)

The REAL problem I'm facing, as I just realized (sorry; early Monday morning / long weekend) is how calls from the realtime API get in.  These calls just sort of arrive from out of the blue, and so there's no authenticated path into the server.  @Martey's point about doing authentication (posted to an earlier version of the question) based on ip address looks promising there, but I'm still wondering if there's a way to get FB to send along user/psw with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use authentication based on IP addresses. By only allowing your address and Facebook's, you would prevent others from accessing the site, but still allow any callbacks from Facebook to arrive.

*In response to the updated question*: If it is possible to add HTTP Basic authentication to a callback URL (i.e. `http://USER:PASSWORD@example.com/`), you would have to do so by adding the username and password directly to the `callback_url` parameter when creating a [real-time subscription](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). Whether or not this will work, however, is dependent on Facebook being able to parse your callback URL and correctly use Basic authentication when communicating with your server.

Comment: Facebook doesn't publish their IP's though.

Comment: Since the OP is concerned about Facebook callbacks, it should be relatively trivial to use his server's access logs to figure on which IP addresses/subnets Facebook requests are coming from.

Comment: yes and it would work, it just seems like a maintenance nightmare.  and how would you know it is a Facebook IP and not somebody trying to look like Facebook?

Comment: Actual Facebook callbacks would contain the same verify_token that was sent when the realtime subscription was created. Since the original question was about protecting the site during development, I do not think that it would be a "nightmare" to maintain, especially if the OP used subnets instead of specific IP addresses.

Comment: I just tried putting the auth into the callback URL, but it 401'ed coming into the server.  This IP authentication isn't perfect, but it's working for now.  So far, I've seen POSTs coming in from 66.220.x.x and 69.171.x.x; your mileage may of course vary. I'm declaring victory for now; thanks for all y'all's help.

Comment: A POST from 69.63.x.x showed up yesterday.  I can't say how current http://compnetworking.about.com/od/traceipaddresses/f/facebook-ip-address.htm will be in the future, but it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just make an exception for Facebook's crawler - you don't necessarily need to return the full content to the crawler, just the meta tags

The user agent is `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`

{edit} why not just exempt the callback URL you're using for the realtime API from your authentication system? There's going to be no other reason for anyone access that URL, and you probably don't have any content there that a regular user can see since all the callback does is decrypt the information form Facebook and process it {edit}

Answer (score 0):

Here's, I think, the right way to do this (which may be what @Igy is referring to above):

```
<Directory /path/to/site>

## Set up the basic password protection                                                                                            
AuthType basic
AuthName YourAuth
AuthUserFile /path/to/auth/file
AuthGroupFile /path/to/group/file
require group YourGroup

# Handle both ALLOW and DENY directives
Order allow,deny

# Allow the facebook servers (sadly, we still have to guess/track the addresses)
Allow from 66.220
Allow from 69.171
Allow from 69.63

# "Satisfy any" means that any of the above techniques will work for access
# Thus, you get in if you have a password or if you are coming from one of the
# specified addresses                                             
Satisfy any

</Directory>
```

So far, so good, anyway...